# How do you automatically deserialize json-root attributes to an object in Retrofit?

Tags: java, gson, retrofit

I am trying to map the root of my json-response to a Java object. It is a list of attributes.

Normally this is easily done with @SerializedName, but in my case I cannot refer to my "Person" object, since my json response looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Peter",
    "height": 10,
    "id": 2,
    "is_default": true
}
```

I know I could manually retrieve each attribute with @SerializedName and then create my own object like this:

```
public class PersonResponse {

    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;

    @SerializedName("height")
    int height;

    @SerializedName("id")
    int id;

    @SerializedName("is_default")
    boolean is_default;

    public Person getPerson() {
        return new Person(name, height,id,is_default);
    }
}
```

But is there another way, where I can do this automatically?

**EDIT for clarification:**

If I had the following JSON:

```
{
  "person": {
    "name": "Peter",
    "height": 10,
    "id": 2,
    "is_default": true
  }
}
```

I could simply do the following in my response:

```
@SerializedName("person")
Person person;
```

And it would automatically map all of the root attributes to the fields in my Person class. However, since the root of my JSON is not a Person object, but simply the attributes of a person, how do I tell this to retrofit?

Comment: what is your question? it is not clear

Comment: Is it possible to tell retrofit, that I want the root object to be a Person? E.g. have an annotation like @RootObject or another simple solution. Since the root object does not have a key/name to refer to it.

Comment: By default it will consider from root, if you want to specify any nested layer then you have to go for annotations @angrybeaver

Comment: I have added some clarifications to the question - maybe it makes more sense now?